# How to style a Python Pandas Dataframe using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, styles

I have the following pandas dataframe with index "NUM":

[image: df]

I want to add color to cells using the followin dictionary:

```
d =  {'R1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  ,'R2': [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
  ,'R3': [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
  ,'R4': [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27]
  ,'R5': [17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
}
```

The values in the dictionary values (lists) are the index in the dataframe.
I want to add background color to the cells, for example in "R1" column color 1 to 10, in "R2" column color 3 to 20 and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.style.apply(
    lambda x: ['background-color:red' if i in d[x.name] else '' 
               for i in np.arange(len(x))+1]
)
```

Output:

[image: Output]